# arrange data into a meshgrid of lat/lon values

Tags: python, reshape

I have three columns in a csv file 'Lat', 'Lon' and 'values' with 158 grids' data as:

[image: dataset]

I want to plot the 'values' in a spatial map with the pcolormesh function for every lat/lon pair. I am using the following code as suggested in one of the pages online:

```
import numpy as np
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import pandas as pd
import random
   
lat = np.array(df_lat_lon['Lat'])
lon = np.array(df_lat_lon['Lon'])
x, y = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
    
 
z = np.array_split(df_lat_lon['values'].values.tolist(), 158)
    
    
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[16, 16])
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
ax.set_extent([19.5, 24, 80, 85], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, zorder=1, facecolor='0.25')
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN, zorder=4)
    
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), zorder=3)
    
plt.show()
```

It seems that I have only 158 z values for 158 (x,y) pairs. I don't know how to reshape the single column of 'values' to 158x158 matrix for the meshgrid to prepare the spatial map. I am getting the following error:

```
nrows, ncols = C.shape

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

An expected image is included as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**updated answer**

OK... after seeing the example map you want to create, I don't think interpolation is what you're searching for... you're just facing the problem of plotting a non-rectangular dataset....

Not sure how to quickly do this in pure cartopy, but that's once again one of the reasons I've created [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) ... it does not require rectangular datasets, it just deals with 1D vectors of coordinates and data-values.

Here's how you would create a plot like the one you've added as an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        lat = [20, 20, 20, 20, 20.25, 20.25, 20.25, 20.25, 20.25, 20.25, 20.25, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5],
        lon = [81.5, 81.75, 82, 82.25, 81, 81.25, 81.5, 81.75, 82, 82.25, 82.5, 80.5, 80.75, 81],
        values = [5,8,2,0,6,1,5,6,8,3,4,1,4,4]))
```

```py
from eomaps import Maps

m = Maps()
m.set_plot_specs(crs=4326)
m.set_data(data=data, xcoord="lon", ycoord="lat", parameter="values")
m.set_shape.rectangles(radius=0.125)
m.plot_map()
```

[image]

**original answer**

---

You need to interpolate your data to the grid by using some grid-interpolation like [scipy's interp2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy-interpolate-interp2d)  before using pcolormesh to visualize it...

alternatively you could use some kind of triangulation to take care of the spatial interpolation...

---

---

... and just to mention :-)
I have designed a (cartopy-based) package ([>> EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps)) that helps with creating maps from 1D data... it can do some triangulations as well... check it out!

```py
from eomaps import Maps
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(dict(lon=[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20], 
                         lat=[11,12,13,14,15,11,12,13,14,15],
                         z=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))

m = Maps()
m.set_data(data=data, crs=4326)

# plot a triangulation of the data
m.set_shape.delaunay_triangulation(masked=False)
m.plot_map(colorbar=False)

# indicate just the triangles used in the delauney triangulation
m.set_shape.delaunay_triangulation(masked=False, flat=True)
m.plot_map(colorbar=False, fc="none", ec="k", lw=0.5, ls=(1, (10, 10)))

# indicate the data-points as ellipses
m.set_shape.ellipses(radius=.15)
m.plot_map(colorbar=False, ec="k")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @raphael. Thank you for the efforts you have made here. I have now edited my question wherein I have also included a reference plot that I want to create with the lat/lon data.

Comment: Hey, I've updated the answer to show you how you could achieve such a plot with EOmaps... (if you want to avoid using a new library then you could try to use a scatterplot with rectangular markers and adjust the marker-size accordingly...)

Comment: Thank you so much @raphael. Doing it by using EOmaps serves my purpose. You saved my life here. Thanks!

Comment: no problem, glad I could help :-)  how about accepting the answer then?

Comment: Thanks @raphael. I accepted your answer. I was not aware of the answer acceptance process. Sorry for the delay in doing so.

Comment: Hi @raphael! Though your answer with EOmaps is exactly what I want, eomaps doesn't seem to get installed in my machine. I used both conda and pip install. If I install cartopy first, then the 0.18.0 version gets installed. eomaps still doesn't seem to get installed as it requires cartopy 0.20.0 or higher. Any idea what can I do with this?

Comment: Hey, oh no, sorry to hear that... It should work just fine with conda...! I'd need some more information to get to the bottom of this.... if you open an issue on Github and add some details I can try to fix it!

Comment: Hi @raphael! Here is the link that I created for the issue. Please check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70728135/error-installing-eomaps-through-conda-and-pip

Comment: @new_coder OK, I've added my 2 cents to why you might experience problems during install...