# Error installing eomaps through conda and pip

Tags: python, pip, conda

I am getting the following error output when trying to install `eomaps` using Conda. I don't know how to solve this. I have also tried the same using `pip` but it didn't seem to solve the problem. Here is the error that Conda reports:

```bash
(base) C:\Windows\system32>conda install -c conda-forge eomaps
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
```

Here is the error that pip reports:

```bash
ERROR: Failed building wheel for cartopy
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for fiona
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cartopy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

**How can I get this to install?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOmaps dev here...

I think the problem is that you're installing packages in your (base) environment! You most probably have some packages installed (previous versions of `cartopy`, `pyproj` etc.?) that conflict with the requirements of EOmaps which is why the conda-solver does not succeed.

I'd strongly suggest working in a fresh environment and NOT in the base environment!
(Checkout [conda user-guide - managing environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html))

As an example, the following should work without any problems:

```
conda create -n eomaps_env python=3.9
conda activate eomaps_env

conda install -c conda-forge eomaps
```

(the name `eomaps_env` and the python-version are both optional and you can change it to whatever name and version you like!)

---

To speed up solving complex dependencies you can also try to use [mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba) (a c++ reimplementation of the conda package manager) which does the very same thing as conda (but solving dependencies works a lot faster):

```
conda create -n eomaps_env python=3.9
conda activate eomaps_env
conda install -c conda-forge mamba

mamba install -c conda-forge eomaps
```

Comment: Better, declare everything upfront and source from **conda-forge**: `mamba create -n eomaps_env -c conda-forge python=3.9 eomaps` If one knows all requirements, it is always more efficacious to declare them at creation time, rather than having the solver run multiple times.

Comment: Thank you @raphael. This solution worked! I just have one question. What does different environments do? Is is not good to work on the base environment? I believe it's a naive question to ask. Suggest me any link where I can read about it in details. Thank you once again!

Comment: The solution suggested by @merv seems to be just a short way of doing the same. For the first time, I preferred the way raphael suggested. Thanks to you too.

Comment: hey @new_coder , great to hear that it's working now!  well... there are numerous sites that provide you with information on how (and why) you should use virtual environments... with a quick search I found this one that looks quite good: https://astrobiomike.github.io/unix/conda-intro  ...or just look at the intro from the conda-doc  https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html

Comment: ... to quote from the first link:   "The “base” conda environment is, like it sounds, kind of our home base inside conda. We wouldn’t want to install lots of complicated programs here, as the more things added, the more likely something is going to end up having a conflict. "  :-)

Comment: Dear @raphael, my problem of installation is solved. I have started working in spyder (in the new environment). While running the code for EOmaps that you suggest last in the previous question gives this error: geopandas could not be imported... 'add_overlay' not working!

Comment: @new_coder... please report any issues with EOmaps on the GitHub page (https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps/issues) otherwise it's impossible for me to keep track!   ... and concerning your "error"... this is a warning not an error!  it just informs you that geopandas (an optional dependency of EOmaps which is not installed by default) is missing and therefore some functionalities (such as the add_overlay function) will not work.   (everything else should work just fine)

Comment: Sure @raphael. I will raise an issue in Github regarding EOmaps. However, I understood that not having geopandas is a warning and not an error. I installed geopandas through conda. But, still it doesn't create the map. There are two blank maps, one with the specified shape(circle or rectangle, whichever we write in the code) and one blank with random axes.

Comment: @new_coder ... as a final comment here... geopandas is NOT required to run the code I've posted! I'm using spyder myself and the map is created just fine (in a fresh environment created with `mamba create -n eomaps_env -c conda-forge python=3.9 eomaps` ) I'll not add any further comments here since this comment section starts to get quite messy, but I'm willing to help with any issues you report on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you so much @raphael for the help you have given me regarding. Being a noob, may be there is some mistake I am doing. I will try it once again and raise an issue in Github if anything comes up.